# archiva standalone vs web

Tags: maven-3, archiva

can some one help me. I want to setup a internal repository for maven. For this i wanted to use Apache Archiva and i'm new to both maven and archiva. My question is what is the exact difference b/w standalone and web archiva installations (i found these 2 ways in archiva documentation).

My intention is to create internal repository to be used by all developers. Every one should get dependencies from there. I have to install archiva in a server with in our organization(LAN). What is the preferable for my situation?

I found steps to install in both ways, but they are little confused as i am new to archiva. Could some one please explain me clearly?

Operating System : Windows
Maven : 3.0.5
Archiva : 1.3.6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standalone distribution is more easy to install.
The wrapper will restart your instance in case of issues.
The important part is to separate content from installation see http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M3/adminguide/standalone.html section "Separating the base from the installation"

Comment: Thanks olamy, i tried in both ways, working same. Finally they both are same, they differ in installation procedure and customizing directories. Will go with Standalone.